# Doctrine2 error : Expected format: Y-m-d

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I get this error message when I deploy my application in the production environment:

> Could not convert database value "2016-06-10 14:57:17" to Doctrine
>   Type date. Expected format: Y-m-d

What does it mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: doctrine can not convert date(datetime) from database to date(date) doctrine.

Comment: can you provide some code of your entity?

Comment: I suspect that you specify in Doctrine that the field type is `Date`, but you are providing it a `DateTime` value.

Answer (score 3):

`2016-06-10 14:57:17` is considered as a `DateTime` and not a `Date`.

`2016-06-10` is the value that you would like to save, so if I consider that your entity has a method for setting date here you have two ways to fix it with `substr` to cut your string to 10 characters `YYYY MM DD`

**Edit your setter to fix by filtering Date**

```
public function setDate($date)
{
    $this->dateNaissance = substr($date,0,10);

    return $this;
}
```

**Trunc your data before setting them to your entity**

```
//However you recover the value, this is an example
$date = "2016-06-10 14:57:17"

$entity->setDate(substr($date,0,10));
//Considerig $om is your manager
$om->persist($entity);
$om->flush();
```

I suggest you the first one.

**substr :**
 http://php.net/manual/fr/function.substr.php